# sleep() prints out line by line with changes made in future lines

Tags: c, sleep

I want to print sth than wait a second and chage it, something like flashing the user, but the sleep() just prints out the future line
is there an alternative or can i make it work with sleep?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif
int main()
{
    printf("abcde!");
    sleep(1);
    printf("\rHello\nLet's play! :^)");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "*the sleep() just prints out the future line*" mean? `sleep` never prints anything. Can you please give the exact expected vs actual output?

Comment: @kaylum when i run it does not at all display the abcde part (i want it to be displayed for a second) insted it gives me nothing and then line of [printf("\rHello\nLet's play! :^)");] but the ! is present so sleep must know the future

Comment: `printf` is generally line buffered. Add `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf`.

Comment: Thanks  @kaylum fflush(stdout); worked!

Comment: Are you deliberately using `\r` instead of `\n`?